# HTTP Post to MySQL inserting Blank Rows

Tags: php, mysql, http, post

I'm trying to setup a post string to enter data directly into the database from a remote system.

Post string example: http://www.domainname.com/insert.php?Phone=07000888888

This returns my expected success message however when I check the database the phone field is blank.

My PHP insert script looks like:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "XXXX";
$password = "XXXX";
$dbname = "Client1";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO LiveFeed (phone)
VALUES ('$_POST[Phone]')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Can anyone figure out why it's inserting a blank row with this?

Comment: if the data comes from the query string, then you should look into `$_GET`, and mind the `P` and `p` of the index in `Phone`

Comment: And also this is vulnerable.

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO LiveFeed (phone) VALUES ('".$_POST["phone"]."')";

Comment: @AndriyStruk are you for real?

Comment: @php_nub_qq vulnerable from what? alien attacks? every body is.

Comment: @Ghost SQL doesn't have a wide variety of vulnerabilities. Additionally this is a vulnerability that is 15+ years old, I just assume everyone knows what I'm talking about.

Comment: Andy, tested your change and I still get a blank row entered into the database.

Comment: I wonder how the op avoided all comments that provide useful information and focused on the one that doesn't :D

Comment: I had a very similar issue to solve recently, so I created this script. I hope it helps someone: https://github.com/cburgdorfer/http-post-to-mysql-insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with the code that as a server admin make me slightly uncomfortable. Hopefully we can fix that and your problem at the same time.

This is what I picked up on.

(I have removed empty lines for brevity)

```
<?php
   // ...
   $phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
   $sql = "INSERT INTO LiveFeed (phone)
   VALUES ('$_POST[Phone]')";
   // ...
```

The first thing is you are correctly escaping the string and then not using the escaped string

```
<?php
   // ...
   $phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
   $sql = "INSERT INTO LiveFeed (phone)
   VALUES ('$phone')";
   // ...
```

However you never inspect the value to see if you have anything.

```
<?php
   // ...
   if(isset($_POST['phone'])){
       $phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
       $sql = "INSERT INTO LiveFeed (phone)
       VALUES ('$phone')";
       // ...
   }else{
       echo '<p><b>Error:</b> "Phone" not given.</p>';
       exit(0); // stop and do no more
   }
   // ...
```

Finally (just in case): If you are sending the data this way `http://example.com/example.php?phone=123456789` that is `$_GET`.

```
<?php
   // ...
   if(isset($_GET['phone'])){
       $phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['phone']);
       $sql = "INSERT INTO LiveFeed (phone)
       VALUES ('$phone')";
       // ...
   }
   // ...
```

One way or another you should now have safe, clean and functional code that does not add empty rows and cannot so readily be abused.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your form, which would help I am assuming you are using GET not POST.

So you need to get your values with GET not POST if the following is the result of the form submission:

```
http://www.domainname.com/insert.php?Phone=07000888888
```

change:

```
$phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO LiveFeed (phone) VALUES ('$_POST[Phone]')";
```

to

```
$phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Phone']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO LiveFeed (phone) VALUES ('$phone')";
```

Additionally for some extra input validation you could do something like:

```
$phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Phone']);

if(!ctype_digit($phone)){
    echo "Incorrect Phone Number format";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO LiveFeed (phone) VALUES ('$phone')";
```

That would make sure the phone number only has numbers in it (if that is indeed what you want and don't have +445498390 type numbers)

Comment: Still entering a blank row for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You code should be like this

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "XXXX";
$password = "XXXX";
$dbname = "Client1";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['phone']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO LiveFeed (phone)
VALUES ('".$phone."')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: This one is also still only inserting a blank row.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.

The code itself was fine, it was the post string URL had an uppercase P in Phone.

once I changed it to phone it's now started working properly.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue and it no matter what filtering I tried in PHP I could not stop the blank line from being inserted into my database records. What finally fixed the issue for me was adding .trim(); to my javascript variable. Hopefully, this will help someone else having similar issue!

Comment: Just to clarify - I added .trim() to my javascript variable that was being sent to PHP script and inserted into mysql database record. Adding the .trim() removed the blank line from from the beginning of my record.